# What is the difference between - and --- operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and in my book author uses --- operator in arithmetic operations and I can't find in google or SoF what is the difference between

```
>>> 5 - 2
3
```

and

```
>>> 5 --- 2
3
```

Update: Yeah, I understand why you all are downvoting this, but I just thought that may be some python specific, which is apparently not.

The book I found this is pretty good one actually - `Python Journeyman by Robert Smallshire` so I will assume it is just an error in the book.

Comment: `--` just becomes a `+`, then `-+` becomes `-` ? That is not a special operator, it's just `-`

Comment: It's not a python question - it's basic integers

Comment: Does the author use that habitually, or for illustrating something specific about operators…? If the former: WTH?! Ditch that book.

Comment: It could also be a typographical mistake; compare how the title has not three dashes, but one em dash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is that the latter doesn't exist. However, there is both [unary `-`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) and [binary `-`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), so the expression is simply `5 - (- (- 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very very simple concept, which is derived from **mathematics** as we know that this is high level language.

```
2--5  // two -- equal to + (so result will be 7)
2---5  // three --- become -(+) equal to - (so result will be -3)
2----5  // four ---- become (+)(+) equal to + (so again will get 7)
2-----5  // five ----- become -(+)(+) become -(+) equal to - (so again will get -3)
```

it's working like toggle so you should always remember these important things, you will never forget or confused

```
###############################

-+ equal to -
+- equal to -
++ equal to +
-- equal to +

#############################
```